# Solr and Jetty deployment issue

Tags: solr, jetty

I am having trouble with getting solr + jetty to work. I am following all
instructions to the letter from - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty. It works like a good. But when I restart jetty multiple times, after 3/4 such restarts it starts hanging. Admin pages just don't load and my app fails to acquire a connection with solr. I also created a work folder - `/opt/solr/work`. I am also setting `tmpdir` to a new path in `/etc/default/jetty`. I can confirm the `tmpdir` is set to the new path from admin dashboard, under args. So it's mostly not an issue with purging of `tmp` files by OS.

What might I be missing? Should I be rather looking at my code and see if I
am not committing correctly?

My configs - Solr 4.0.0 and jetty from example. Ubuntu 12.04 with Open JDK 7.

**Edit:**

I am running Jetty 8, bundled with Solr example on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine. When I use start.jar and server does not come up properly, while shutting down jetty throws ThreadPoolException - Failing to stop threads.

Here is a dump of stack trace:

```
2012-12-27 23:00:15.084:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:1 threads could not be stopped
2012-12-27 23:00:15.084:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:Couldn't stop Thread[qtp766488133-16,5,main]
2012-12-27 23:00:15.085:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool: at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
2012-12-27 23:00:15.085:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool: at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
2012-12-27 23:00:15.085:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool: at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
2012-12-27 23:00:15.085:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1425)
2012-12-27 23:00:15.086:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool: at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.awaitTermination(Executors.java:636)
2012-12-27 23:00:15.086:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool: at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.close(SolrCore.java:835)
2012-12-27 23:00:15.086:INFO:oejut.QueuedThreadPool: at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.getCoreStatus(CoreAdminHandler.java:865)
```

Comment: can you edit and add in the more from that ThreadPoolException?

Comment: Added a stacktrace. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: ok, think that exception is a red herring, likely a request blocked on  something internal to solr and not getting cleaned up on close fully.

Comment: So it is definitely a solr side issue and not a config issue like tmpdir or work directory setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is with `solrconfig.xml`.

If I remove `/browse` request handler from `solrconfig` problem goes away. So not a solr or jetty issue, but most likely related to config of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Exception doesn't point out anything interesting, I would recommend that when it is hanging that you now take a thread dump of the whole server and analyze that for what is blocking correct startup.  These can take a bit of trial and error to sort out what is what but should let you clue into what is holding things up.  Note that the threads that start with qtp in the thread dump are rarely the issue, they are for processing requests so while there are likely a number of them there that is not an indication they are an issue.  Common issues are things like database pooling that is 'await' on a pooled resource and things like that.

Comment: I do not use any database in the my app, its just solr for storage. Also since the issue is coming up on startup, I am not sure if it is to do with requests being blocked. Do you know if there are any known issues with shutting down of jetty? May be I am not stopping it cleanly and hence problems when starting again. I can load jetty as heavily as required, up to 50+ requests/second and no issues. But problem comes when I need to stop server and start it again.

Comment: A thread dump should sort that out.  I am certainly not saying that it is NOT a configuration issue, just that a thread dump will highlight what is going on.  I mentioned database connection pooling as an example only.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GPnAzF1q here is the threaddump. I am not very experienced in analyzing it, but still trying.

Comment: might need to take a series of thread dumps to see if a particular thread is spinning, but I would take a stab and say that perhaps SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1336) is blocking a more complete startup? The actual jetty threads seem fine.